# Is it possible to insert 'null' or blank values where certain 'piars' of values already exist using DAX in Power BI?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am using this:

```
'Total = SUMX(
FILTER(
    Table1,
    Table1[Client] = EARLIER( Table1[Client] )
),
Table1[Sales])'
```

In the table I have many results that are duplicated in the column created here, I still have a use for the value but I want a way to possibly insert 'nulls' or blanks in instances where 'Client/Sales' pairs (across the rows) are already accounted for. Is there a way to take both columns and when an instance is 'repeated' to insert a blank?
This is what things look like now...

| Client | Sales | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1hk4 | 4 | 8 |
| 1hk4 | 2 | 8 |
| 4f33 | 1 | 3 |
| 5t23 | 3 | 5 |
| 4f33 | 1 | 3 |
| 1hk4 | 2 | 8 |
| 4f33 | 1 | 3 |
| 5t23 | 2 | 5 |

This is what I'm trying to go for:

| Client | Sales | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1hk4 | 4 | 8 |
| 1hk4 | 2 |  |
| 4f33 | 1 | 3 |
| 5t23 | 3 | 5 |
| 4f33 | 1 |  |
| 1hk4 | 2 |  |
| 4f33 | 1 |  |
| 5t23 | 2 |  |

The reason I'm trying for this is because in the report I am unable to turn off summarize and the data doesn't relay well. Ideally I want to be able to see the unique result by client.

Comment: This can be don if you have an index column which is unique for each row, or at least unique for each row for any given client.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you can add a column to your table with a unique index for each row:

[image]

Then you can add a calculated column like this:

```
Total = 
var currnetIndex = [Index]
var currentClient = [Client]
var minIndex = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Data'[Index]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Data'),
        'Data'[Client] = currentClient
    )
)

return
IF(
    currnetIndex = minIndex, 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Data'[Sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Data),
            'Data'[Client] = currentClient
        )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Which will give you a table looking like this:
[image]

This solution works if the index is unique only to the user as well.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Now to see if the report level works out right...